# NSTextAttachment Tint Color

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsattributedstring, tintcolor

I'm trying to create a label with text, prepended with an icon, but unfortunately I'm unable to change the color of just the icon. It's always tinted with its default color.

This is how I do it:

```
var titleStringAttribute = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")

var iconAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "trash")!)
iconAttachment.image?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate) // Does not work?!

titleStringAttribute.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment))

// Appending bold text to attributedText

theLabel.attributedText = titleStringAttribute
```

I also took a look into StackOverflow and other websites on the internet, but nothing helped yet.

I'm working with iOS 13.5.

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withTintColor(_:renderingMode:)` doesn't *change* the image you're calling it on. All it does it return a *new* `UIImage` for you to use, but you're not making use of it.

Update your code to first create the default trash image, then create a new image from that using `withTintColor`, and then finally give your attachment that new image in its initializer:

```
let titleStringAttribute = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")

let trashImage = UIImage(systemName: "trash")!
let redTrashImage = trashImage.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
let iconAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: redTrashImage)

titleStringAttribute.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment))

// Appending bold text to attributedText

theLabel.attributedText = titleStringAttribute
```